# Was heißt „grau in grau“?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, usage, context

Neulich habe ich einen Satz gelesen, wo ich einen Teil des Satzes gefunden habe, den ich nicht verstehe.

Der Satz ist : „**Gerade hier in unserer Stadt ist es doch grau in grau**“.

Der Satz ist einfach, aber ich kann nicht die Referenz „**grau in grau**“ verstehen.

Es könnte nicht so einfach wie "gray in gray" sein. Es macht in Englisch keinen Sinn.

Können Sie bitte mir helfen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Grau in grau" bedeutet, dass etwas im Wesentlichen grau ist, aufgelockert von mehr Grau ;) Im Englischen würde man dieses trostlose Szenario wohl mit "gloomy", "bleak", "grey and drab" umschreiben.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe :) Das macht alles klar.

Comment: *Das Wetter war wochenlang nur grau in grau.*

Comment: auch eine beschreibung für tristesse und monotonie...